# Is calling an interface nested inside an abstract generic class bad programming practice

Tags: oop, design-principles

Using the code below as an example

```
public abstract class Foo<T,V>{
   // ...some methods

   public interface IFoo<S,U>{
      S doSomething(U input);
    }   

}

    class MyClass implements Foo.IFoo<String, Integer>{}
```

Is calling the interface like that bad OOP or there is nothing wrong with that. Note the interface has different generic parameters from the abstract class.

Comment: The fact that the interface is public either implies intended usage or bad design. So it depends on the actual use case.

Comment: Can you please give /describe the use-case where this would be a bad design?

Comment: bad design: e.g. if `IFoo` is supposed to be used only within `Foo`, but was declared public instead. Or if `IFoo` is something that needs to be its own file (e.g. `FileReader`), but was for some reason coupled with `Foo`. Or if `IFoo` is intended for inherited classes but is not `protected`.

Comment: intended usage example: `IFoo` is part of `Foo`'s API.

Comment: I see. That really helps Thanks.